# 1-form on Riemann Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Good evening, I can not prove the following result:

Let $\omega $ be a meromorphic 1-form on $ \mathbb {C} _ {\infty} = \mathbb {C} \cup \infty $ such that $ \omega_{|\mathbb{C}} = f (z) dz $. Show that f is ratio of polynomial functions. 
Any suggestions on how to develop the demonstration? 
thanks.

Comment: Hint: On another cover $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\} \cup \{\infty\}$, write $\omega = \tilde f(\tilde z) d\tilde z$. Then use $z = 1/\tilde z$ and compare coefficient of Laurent series of $f$ and $\tilde f$.

Comment: Specifically, how can I compare them? Can you give me the details, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more conceptual proof. Consider first the behaviour of $f$ at infinity, when we change the coordinates to $\frac{1}{z}$ we get $\omega=-\frac{1}{z^2}f(\frac{1}{z})dz$. Now $\frac{1}{z^2}f(\frac{1}{z})$ must have a pole or a finite value at $z=0$.
So we can say that there is a $k$ such that $z^kf(z)$ is bounded at infinity. Now this function has finite number of poles. By subtracting the principal parts of these poles we get an entire function, bounded at infinity, so it must be constant. This then shows that $f$ is a rational function.

Comment: Why $\frac{1}{z^2} f(\frac{1}{z})$ must have a pole or a finite value at $z=0$? and We Can Say That there is a $k$ such that $z^{k} f(z)$ is bounded at infinity. Why Has this function finite number of poles? Either way, By subtracting the principal parts of These poles we get an Entire function, bounded at infinity, so can we conclude that it is holomorphic?

Comment: The original form is meromorphic, so it has a finite value or a pole at each point, including infinity. By changing coordinates the form is represented by $\frac{1}{z^2}f(\frac{1}{z})dz$ with the point $z=0$ coresponding to infinity. So at this point is a zero or pole of finite order (positive or negative), if we multiply by the appropriate exponent of $z$ and change back we get that $z^kf(z)$ is bounded. The zeros and poles are isolated points and $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ is compact so there are only finitely many of them.

Comment: Entire functions bounded at infinity are constant.

Comment: tell me if it is right.due to a change of 1-forms,I can say that $f(z)=-\frac{1}{z^2}f(\frac{1}{z})$.
since $f(\frac{1}{z})$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ has a finite number of zeros and poles. the only point to be studied is the case $z = 0$.when $z=0$, $f(\frac{1}{z})$ has a pole or a finite value.then multiplying by an appropriate $z^k$ we make the function $f(z)$ holomorphic, limited and consequently constant. then the only possibility is that $f(z)$ was ratio of polynomials. since only the functions that are ratio of polynomials,when multiplied by $z^k$, they become constant. right?

Comment: can someone tell me if the proof that I have written in the comment is correct? or is it completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As suggest in the comment, on another cover $\mathbb C$ (which corresponds to $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\} \cup \{\infty\}$ with coordinates $\tilde z$), write 
$$\omega = \tilde f(\tilde z)$$

On the intersection of two coordinate $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$, we have $z = 1/\tilde z$, then

$$d\tilde z = d(1/ z) = -\frac{1}{ z^2} d z . $$

Write $f(z) = \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n z^n$ and $\tilde f(\tilde z) = \sum_{n=m}^\infty b_n \tilde z^n$ for some $k, m\in \mathbb Z$, then

$$ \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n z^n dz = f(z) dz = \tilde f(\tilde z) d\tilde z = \sum_{n=m}^\infty b_n \tilde z^n d\tilde z = \sum_{n=m}^\infty b_n z^{-n} \bigg(-\frac{1}{z^2}\bigg)dz$$

$$ \Rightarrow \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n z^n  = \sum_{n=m}^\infty (-b_n) z^{-n-2}$$
Then compare coefficients to see that $a_n = b_n = 0$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: Thanks, But I don't understand very well how I can conclude now.

Comment: You didn't define $\tilde f$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: That is in the comment.

Comment: Answers should be self-contained, and not reference comments.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Changed as suggested. Thanks!